# Отделяется ли запятой "таким образом"?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, отделяется ли запятой в начале предложения оборот "таким образом"? Например, "Таким образом(,) на молоко нужно получать декларацию".
Спасибо

Answer (score 12):

Вводное словосочетание "таким образом" имеет значение вывода из того, что утверждалось ранее (итак, следовательно) и обособляется как в начале, так и в середине предложения, но его нужно отличать от обстоятельства со значением "так, таким способом", например: "Думая таким образом, он мчался вперед".

Answer (score 6):

Вводные слова и словосочетания, указывающие на связь мыслей в предложении, последовательность изложения, выделяются запятыми: в общем, во-первых, во-вторых, впрочем, в частности, главное, к примеру и др. Словосочетание "таким образом" выделяется запятыми, когда этот оборот подытоживает сказанное ранее и синонимичен слову *следовательно*, то есть является вводной конструкцией.

"Таким образом, мы приходим к выводу..." (или "Мы, таким образом, приходим к выводу..."). Здесь "таким образом" означает *следовательно*.

"Таким образом он уравнивает себя с другими" (или "Он таким образом уравнивает себя с другими"). Здесь "таким образом" означает *посредством этого, таким способом*.

В вашем случае указанная запятая нужна. Ср.: *Таким образом , (следовательно) на молоко нужно получать декларацию.* Здесь "таким образом" подытоживает сказанное ранее...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос можно найти не только в правилах, но и определиться по смыслу, даже не зная или забыв соответствующее правило.

И так, у Вас есть два варианта, и выбор зависит от того, что Вы хотите сказать.

1. “Таким *образом*, на молоко *нужно* получать декларацию.” (запятая присутствует и ударение, дифференцированное, на словах **образом** и **нужно**)

Смысл сказанного: состоялась дискуссия или разговор на предмет **необходимости** получения декларации, и которая завершилась недвусмысленным выводом.
Например, у Вас был спор по поводу того, надо ли получать декларацию на молоко или не надо.

2. “*Таким* образом на молоко нужно получать декларацию.” (запятая отсутствует и ударение на слове **таким**)

Смысл сказанного: состоялось обсуждение самого **процесса**/**способа** получения декларации на молоко, и это - заключительная фраза.
Например, при инструктаже нового работника, или когда из-за какой-то ошибки вам было отказано в выдаче декларации и нужно было снова объяснить соответствующие правила.